# styles are not inherited when content page is not in root folder but subfolder

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages

I have a MasterPage at Rool level.

I have a content page:

login.aspx - inside a subfolder ~/members,

now anything that has runat="server" inside  masterpage is not inherting its styles in login.aspx page  but if i put my login.aspx in root folder its working

iv also tried to link the stylesheet in login.aspx page like this

```
  <link href="../App_Themes/blue/Unbound.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and in my master page my link to stylesheet is like this:

```
  <link href="~/App_Themes/blue/Unbound.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the master page, add a `runat="server"` attribute to the stylesheet link. Otherwise it won't pick up the absolute path (e.g. the `~/`).